# how to add a new row in repeater control from javascript in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, asprepeater

I have using the following HTML block within a Repeater control. I can add rows to the HTML table from client side (JavaScript) and values are added. When the page post backs by a button click, the table become empty. But I am not able to get the values from the binding repeater control in server side too. It shows nothing. How can I add the values to repeater from client side or binding with HTML table ?

```
<table id="tblSelectlist" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <th class="hidden-480">
                City
            </th>
            <th class="hidden-480">
                State
           </th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <asp:repeater id="repSelectlist" runat="server" enableviewstate="true">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td class="left">
                        <label id="lblSelectcompany" runat="server">
                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DataItem.CustName")%></a>
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="hidden-480">
                        <label id="lblSelectCity" runat="server">
                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DataItem.custCity")%>
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label id="lblSelectState" runat="server">
                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DataItem.custstate")%>
                        </label>
                    </td>  
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:repeater>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If I use `runat="server"` for the HTML table, it shows the following error:

> Value of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater' cannot be converted
>   to 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow'.

Answer (score 0):

Use the HeaderTemplate and FooterTemplate sections of the repeater control.

```
<asp:repeater id="repSelectlist" runat="server" enableviewstate="true">
<HeaderTemplate>
  <table id="tblSelectlist" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>
  Name
  </th>
  <th class="hidden-480">
  City
  </th>
  <th class="hidden-480">
  State
  </th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
</HeaderTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>
 <tr>
 <td class="left">
 <label id="lblSelectcompany" runat="server">
 <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DataItem.CustName")%></a>
 </label>
 </td>
 <td class="hidden-480">
 <label id="lblSelectCity" runat="server">
 <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DataItem.custCity")%>
 </label>
 </td>
 <td>
 <label id="lblSelectState" runat="server">
 <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DataItem.custstate")%>
 </label>
 </td>                                                                              
 </tr>
</ItemTemplate>

<FooterTemplate>
  </tbody>
  </table>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:repeater>
```